# How to add form in a component of select type?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have to make a user registration form. After completing the form and pressing the button submit, the values from the form need to be added in a component of `<p id="data></p>`. Can someone help me here? It's working only for the drop-down list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form >
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" id="mySelect"> <br>
    Male <input type="radio" id="male" name="male" id="mySelect"><br>
    Female <input type="radio" id="female" name="female" id="mySelect"><br>
    Country: <br>
    <select name="country" size="4" id="mySelect">
    <option value="c1">c1</option>
    <option value="c2">c2</option>
    <option value="c3">c3</option>
    <option value="c4">c4</option>
    <option value="c5">c5</option>
    </select> <br>
    <br>
</form>



<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="data"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + x.options[i].text + "<br>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not able to get what is your question. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

Here is couple things you should change:

- DO NOT use same id for different elements on page: it causes issues like you experienced;
- you duplicated id attribute for every form element - don't do that please, attributes shouldn't be duplicated for single element;
- please read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - getElementById returns single element which match or null;
- use getElementsByClassName instead giving the same classname to every form element, like "sys-form-element"; in this case getElementsByClassName("sys-form-element") returns collection of matched elements which includes every form field which you could parse then with your "myFunction" - just update it to discover element type and hadle texts, radios and selects differently;